# Changed my BB and Crankset at the mechanic today, but now it sits real far out

Tags: crankset

Topic posted, can anyone tell me if this looks right? I used to run Hollowtech BBs and my mechanic changed them to this square tapered style? I don't know if they're supposed to look this exposed and sitting so far out.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: Why did your LBS downgrade from HT2 to square taper? Also, they put way too much grease on that drive side BB cup, jeez.

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarily see a problem. Looking at the gap in the spindle area is a superficial way of judging it, but even so it doesn't look particularly weird. It's too wide if the chainline is wrong and could be better without clearance issues, and it's not too wide if the chainline is either as intended by the manufacturer (ie they put in the FSA spec spindle length, tested that everything works, and moved on, which is the expedient thing to do most of the time) or has been tweaked in some way to make it better for a specific bike, i.e. running a little longer spindle on a 130-oriented road crank to have better chainline on a 135 disc road bike, which is also reasonable.

FSA lists spindle spec lengths for everything and most shops/mechanics will provide a record of the length used on the receipt or work order. So you could look at that if you're second guessing. You could also measure the chainline as-is and see if it's in the right range. (It's pretty common for it to be out in front a few mm even when things are right per manufacturer spec, so don't jump to conclusions here.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these cranks are installed unusually wide. Either the bottom bracket has too long axle, or FSA's specification is really unusual. Another consideration is that square taper has been mostly deprecated for last 15 years except for some niches, so installing square taper bottom bracket in 2021 is already an odd choice by itself.